# django admin forms.ModelForm validation for blank IntegerField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How can you make it in Django admin so that when you click save if the forms.IntegerField is blank to return a validation error?. Currently, if you save the model it will still accept the transaction.

Any suggestions?

**forms.py`**

```
class CarInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    car_type = forms.CharField(disabled=True)
    car_qty = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1)

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        exclude = ['created']
```

**`admin.py`**

```
class CarInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CarOrderItem
    extra = 1
    max_num = 1
    form = CarInlineForm
    exclude = [
        'created',
    ]


class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CarInline]
```

Comment: did you try adding `required=True` in that form.IntergerFIeld ?

Comment: Model - car_qty = models.IntegerField(null=False,
                                  blank=False,
                                  validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])

Comment: Always add `null=False` when `NULL` is not a meaningful value. Most of the times numeric fields should not be null since `0`, or `1` is usually a sensible default.